# How to enabled button using javascript in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to enabled the disabled button using on clicking of the html button in asp.net.
but its not getting enbled.
here is my code

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setDefaults() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
            btn.disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <button  onclick="javascript:setDefaults();" causesvalidation="false">Defaults</button>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="btn" Enabled="false" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

please let me know whats wrong with my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using button but is it html or asp.net?

use

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Defaults" onclick="setDefaults();" />
```

or

```
<asp:button runat="server" text="Defaults" OnClientClick="javascript:setDefaults()" id="myButton"></asp:button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like it should be working. It works for regular html, at least.
I would suggest turning on developer tools (for google chrome), or firebug to make sure that no exceptions are being thrown.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setDefaults() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:setDefaults();" >Click!</button>
    <button id="btn" Disabled="true" >Click2!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is as simple and its just you need to do as

```
.enabled = true;


.disabled= false;
```

(Or)
you can try this way

```
document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').disabled = true;

document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
```